# Pyomo: Compute IIS, remove corresponding constraint and resolve

Tags: gurobi, pyomo, cbc, irreducible-infeasible-subset

I am using pyomo together with a bunch of solvers (gurobi, cbc, etc.).
I am able to compute the IIS (with gurobi, not cbc), and write it in a `*.ilp` file.

What I would like to achieve would be to identifiy a constraint (or several ones) making the problem infeasible, remove it and resolve the problem.

To do so I have mainly two issues:

1. I am not able to read the `*.ilp` file with pyomo
2. Even if I was, I am not sure I would be able to link constraints in the pyomo model to constraints in the `*.ilp` file (and vice-versa)